# Logic app parameter from http1 (session id) to http2

Tags: azure, https, parameters, azure-logic-apps, dynamically-generated

I need to pass the session ID from the HTTP1 to HTTP 2:

[image]

As u can see we are getting the session ID from the HTTP1 same session ID I need to pass in HTTP2 dynamically.

[image]

How can I achieve this:

[image]

The Last step is to connect the HTTP2 - to blob storage so that from the URL I get the data into my blob storage, but I am stuck in the session ID part please give some idea on that.

Have a look:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following syntax to read the value from HTTP1 and pass this value directly in HTTP2

```
body('HTTP')?['sessionId']
```

Comment: Can you explain little more any images u have where to pass??

Comment: I have done this but now getting error, {
  "errors": [
    {
      "type": "METHOD_NOT_SUPPORTED",
      "message": "Content type 'null' not supported"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Could you please share the updated flow?? Looks like you are not setting the content type on http action

Comment: I have added a image and I am paasing in HTTP 2 contentype - application/jsson

Comment: and is the http2 sending the error?? have you tried the consuming the http call from postman? btw the image shows that you are doing a GET call, content-type is not required as GET does not require a request body

Comment: Yes I tried with postman below is the output, Yes Get doesn't required content type I tried that also after removing content type also same error. responseStatus,id,InputId,external_id__v,name__v,title__v,file,major_version_number__v,minor_version_number__v,type__v,lifecycle__v,status__v,agreement_type__c,information_classification__c,group__c,owning_site__c,owning_department__v,record_series_code__c,periodic_review_frequency__c,errors,rowId

SUCCESS,27,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1

SUCCESS,28,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,3

Comment: There is a issue with logic app will not support content type application/json -octet. I have achieved the same thing using Azure function.Thanks Mandar for your quick responses.